# How to filter items in a list with ReactJS and Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am rendering a list of elements and doing the pagination, each page of my list contains 3 elements.

I'm inserting an `` field where the user can filter any product he wants. The filter is working. The problem is that it is filtering only the items on the current page.

For example, if I search for a product that is on page 2 of my list, the product does not appear.

Can you tell me how I can fix this?

As I'm using a lot files, I put my code into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pagination-active-forked-px5gj?file=/src/App.js)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you were running into was that you were paginating the data before filtering it.

So, I went ahead and modified the code to filter and then paginate. I filtered it using a `useMemo` hook as filtering can be expensive when done on a large list.

```
  const [searchPerfume, setSearchPerfume] = useState("");
  // Filter the data based on the search string
  const filteredPerfumes = useMemo(() => {
    return data.filter((perfume) =>
      perfume.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchPerfume.toLowerCase())
    );
  }, [data, searchPerfume]);

  // Paginate the data
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [perfumesPerPage, setPerfumesPerPage] = useState(3);
  const currentPerfumes = filteredPerfumes.slice(
    (currentPage-1) * perfumesPerPage,
    currentPage * perfumesPerPage
  );
  const pages = Math.ceil(filteredPerfumes.length / perfumesPerPage);
  // Reset current page if there are fewer pages than the current page
  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentPage > pages) {
      setCurrentPage(1);
    }
  }, [currentPage, pages]);
  // Get the range of pages in an array
  const pageNumbers = Array(pages)
    .fill(null)
    .map((val, index) => index + 1);
```

[Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pagination-active-forked-qjjx7?file=/src/components/Card/Card.jsx)